# Function volume keys get stuck; volume raises to max/min rapidly

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, volume-control

I have two function keys for raising and lowering sound volume in keys [3] and [4]. Occasionally, when raising or lowering the volume, it's like the key gets stuck and the volume quickly raises to maximum or goes to zero as if I didn't release the key.

My Google searches weren't very successful because the results were mostly littered with unrelated problems about the volume in Ubuntu. I did find this old bug report that seems to describe something similar. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/194214

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity. This sound problem doesn't happen with any application in particular. Laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L755.

This problem never happens when using the dedicated key on my external keyboard.

**edit**: This still happens occasionally. I'm not on Ubuntu 16.04 using i3.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo nano 85-keyboard-configuration.rules
```

Make changes to make your file look like this:

```
  # Set up a single virtual console.
  SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="tty[1-6]", RUN+="console-setup-tty /dev/%k",
  ATTR{[dmi/id]product_name}=="SATELLITE L750*"

  # Framebuffer console created.  Set up the font on all virtual consoles
  # again.  This races with Plymouth if fbcon is built into the kernel; but
  # the worst case should simply be that fonts don't get set up properly.
  SUBSYSTEM=="graphics", KERNEL=="fbcon", RUN+="console-setup-tty fbcon"
```

To save your modifications:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: I can't confirm this now, because I have switched to Mint Cinnamon recently, but thanks for the answer.